# How to handle link data detector UITextView / Link embed in webview iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c

In our application we embed our SAFETY link in textview/webview as attached in the image. Before iOS 10 when tap is received

`- openURL:` method will be fired and we handle redirection as below.

```
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if ([url shouldHandleLocally])
    {
        return [self openURLApp:url isFromOtherApp:NO];
    }
    return [super openURL:url];
}
```

Now in iOS 10 neither of this method fired `-canOpenURL: -openURL:` and in documentation it is mentioned

> - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 10_0, "Please use openURL:options:completionHandler: instead")
>     NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");

Even below method is not fired.

```
- (void)openURL:(NSURL*)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options completionHandler:(void (^ __nullable)(BOOL success))completion {
}
```

How to handle this case ? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your link lives in a UITextView then you should use the `textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)` function of [UITextViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextviewdelegate).  Your delegate will be able to catch the interaction with a link in the UITextView, you can then call your logic to handle the URL internally. Return `NO` from the delegate method to prevent iOS from opening the URL in its browser when appropriate.